# Bayesian Network

Tags: artificial-intelligence, probability, bayesian-networks

I have following bayesian network :
[image]

I was asked to find:

Value of P(b)
The solution

```
P(b) = ΣA={a,¬a} P(A)P(b|A)
= 0.1 × 0.5 + 0.9 × 0.8 = 0.77
```

and value of P(d/a)
The solution:

```
P (d|a) = ΣB={b,¬b} P (d|B)p(B|a)
= 0.9 × 0.5 + 0.2 × 0.5 = 0. 55
```

How did they come up with above formula?
What rule they have used to find marginal probability from bayesian network graph?

I understand basic joint probability distribution formula which is just product of individual probabilities given its parents.

Some explanation and resources relating to this will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found my answer.

It uses Marginal Probabilities.

The formula is:

```
P(X/Y) =  ΣZ={all possible values of z} P(X/Y,Z)P(Z|Y)
```

Now you can easily find above two probabilities.